# Creating an executable file from a Java project using Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am creating an android project using libgdx and android studio.
I was able to create a runnable jar using the command

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```

However I am interested in creating an executable file from my java project (like you would do on the shell using GCJ). Is there any way to do that using gradle?

Thanks.

Comment: does adding a manifest file not solve your problem ??

Comment: @EkanshRastogi no, I don´t want to create a runnable .jar file. I want to create an .exe file.

Comment: @DanielOliveira Java does not produce `.exe` files, the whole concept of `java` and its `jvm` is to be cross platform by producing mid-level `byte-code` instead of machin level `binaries`. `.exe` files are machine level `binary` files. So what you asked is not possible at all.

Comment: It is possible, I have done it for small projects using GCJ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java I just dont know if there is any gradlew command to use CGJ directly

Comment: It's probably not hard to get an executable once you have a jar.  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=exe%20wrapper%20for%20jar